# Android, Rest api post error - Access denied

Tags: android, rest, drupal

I am a beginner. This is my first Android app. I have issue posting data to my Drupal server from Android. I am using Rest api.

I can login as Drupal admin user, I get the session id, session name and token. My problem is posting the data. I think the problem is authentication on posting. I don't know how to do that part.

Both INTERNET and ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE is declared in manifest

Login part (Working)

```
 private class LoginProcess extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
       String address = "http://app.flickgo.com/apistuff/user/login.json";
       HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
       String requestBody;
       Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
       Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
       params.put("username", "myUsername");
       params.put("password", "myPassword");

       // encode parameters
       Iterator entries = params.entrySet().iterator();
       while (entries.hasNext()) {
           Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) entries.next();
           builder.appendQueryParameter(entry.getKey().toString(), entry.getValue().toString());
           entries.remove();
       }
       requestBody = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

       try {
           URL url = new URL(address);
           urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
           urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
           urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
           OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
           BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "utf-8"));
           writer.write(requestBody);
           writer.flush();
           writer.close();
           outputStream.close();

           JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
           InputStream inputStream;
           // get stream
           if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() < HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST) {
               inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
           } else {
               inputStream = urlConnection.getErrorStream();
           }
           // parse stream
           BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
           String temp, response = "";
           while ((temp = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
               response += temp;
           }
           // put into JSONObject
           jsonObject.put("Content", response);
           jsonObject.put("Message", urlConnection.getResponseMessage());
           jsonObject.put("Length", urlConnection.getContentLength());
           jsonObject.put("Type", urlConnection.getContentType());

           return jsonObject.toString();
       } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
           return e.toString();
       }
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
       super.onPostExecute(result);
       //create an intent to start the ListActivity
       Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
       //pass the session_id and session_name to ListActivity
       intent.putExtra("My_result", result);
       //start the ListActivity
       startActivity(intent);
   }
}
```

Post part, not working.
On the SecondActivity, i want to post some data.
This is where i have problems. I keep getting the message access denied.
How can i use the session id, session name or token from result (intent.putExtra("My_result", result) - from Login page) to post content? Is this actually the correct way to do it? If there is a better way, please let me know.

```
private class JsonPostRequest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            String address = "http://app.flickgo.com/apistuff/node.json";
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            json.put("title", "Dummy Title");
            json.put("type", "article");
            String requestBody = json.toString();
            URL url = new URL(address);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "utf-8"));
            writer.write(requestBody);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            outputStream.close();

            InputStream inputStream;
            // get stream
            if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() < HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST) {
                inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            } else {
                inputStream = urlConnection.getErrorStream();
            }
            // parse stream
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String temp, response = "";
            while ((temp = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                response += temp;
            }
            // put into JSONObject
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("Content", response);
            jsonObject.put("Message", urlConnection.getResponseMessage());
            jsonObject.put("Length", urlConnection.getContentLength());
            jsonObject.put("Type", urlConnection.getContentType());
            return jsonObject.toString();
        } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
            return e.toString();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, result + "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //Log.i(LOG_TAG, "POST RESPONSE: " + result);
        //mTextView.setText(result);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you declared the internet permission in manifest file?

Comment: Yes, both INTERNET and ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE is declared in manifest

Comment: Access denied error is returned from server or you got that from some thrown exception?

Comment: I tested the rest api in Postman. And i was able to Post content. My problem is authentication on posting new content. How do i use the session id, session name to post new content.

Comment: I think the api required an auth data from login response. But I do not know which data server required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. I didn't set the cookies the correct way.

```
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Cookie",session_name+"="+session_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet:

```
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(requestBody);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
    // ..
```

Bytheway, you'd better use OkHttp and doing POST request will be much simpler

Comment: What about the token and session id. Don't i need to set it in the header to make a post? Thanks for advice i will take a look at OkHttp

Comment: You probably need them if the server expects so. In the snippet  of code you provided there are no these headers. So just add them

Comment: That's my problem. I don't know how to add these headers

Comment: Use for each header: urlConnection.setRequestProperty("name", "value");

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("username", "myUsername");
params.put("password", "myPassword");
postLogin(getApplicationContext(),"http://app.flickgo.com/apistuff/node.json",params)

public JSONObject postLogin(Context mContext, String REQUEST_URL,Map<String, Object> params) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                BufferedReader reader = null;
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(REQUEST_URL);
                    StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();

                    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> param : params.entrySet()) {
                        if (postData.length() != 0) postData.append('&');
                        postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
                        postData.append('=');
                        postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
                    }
                    byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", token); //Set your token
                    connection.setConnectTimeout(8000);
                    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    connection.setUseCaches(false);
                    connection.setDoOutput(true);
                    connection.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);
                    connection.connect();
                    StringBuilder sb;
                    int statusCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                    if (statusCode == 200) {
                        sb = new StringBuilder();
                        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                        String line;
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(line);
                        }
                        jsonObject = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
                    }
                    connection.disconnect();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (reader != null) {
                        try {
                            reader.close();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                return jsonObject;
            }
```